# How to select specific button from multi buttons inside each helper in Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

```
{{#each posts}}    
   <input type="hidden" value="{{this.id}}" name="storeInput">
   <input type="button" value="Save" name="store">
{{/each}}
```

how to select specific button with jQyery?

Comment: you can just a selector and target your button ! or can you please be more clear so we can help you

Comment: What are you going to do when you select the button?

Comment: @G.aziz how to select a button from many buttons inside each helper they can't be the same id?

Comment: get the value of hidden input @Bibberty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, this event listener will filter on the buttons and the look at the previous sibling.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.target.matches('[type="button"]')) {
    console.log(e.target.previousElementSibling.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="storeInput">
<input type="button" value="Save" name="store">
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="storeInput">
<input type="button" value="Save" name="store">
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="storeInput">
<input type="button" value="Save" name="store">
<input type="hidden" value="4" name="storeInput">
<input type="button" value="Save" name="store">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the post id on the client, you can generate an id or class based on this.id

```
<input type="hidden" id="post-{{this.id}}" value="{{this.id}}" name="storeInput">
```

then in js

```
const buttonEl = $('#post-' + post.id);
```

You don't need 'post-' but it's nice to namespace things.

I'm positive there's a better way to do this btw

Comment: i don't have a ref to the post id in js, so what can i do?